# SharePoint 2016 There is no file with URL '_catalogs/wp/DocumentSetProperties.dwp' in this Web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a new installation of SharePoint server 2016, I have setup a new web application and now trying to create a new site collection and I am getting the error :

> There is no file with URL '_catalogs/wp/DocumentSetProperties.dwp' in
>   this Web.

I redid the web application a few times without any success. 
thanks for any help

Edit: With poweershell I get the error

```
New-SPSite -Url $Site -OwnerAlias $Owner -Template STS#2
```

> New-SPSite : There is no file with URL
>   '_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master' in this Web

Here is the full powershell script:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$siteURL = "http://somewebapp.com/sites/test2"
$sitePrimaryOwner = "domain\secretusername"
$siteSecondaryOwner = "domain\secretusername"
$siteName = "Test Site"
$siteTemplate = "STS#0"
$siteDescription = "This is a test site"

New-SPSite -Url $siteURL -OwnerAlias $sitePrimaryOwner -SecondaryOwnerAlias 
$siteSecondaryOwner -Name $siteName -Template $siteTemplate -Description 
$siteDescription
```

Comment: Where did you define `$site`? Please post this code also here.

Comment: I up[dated the post with the script they are just variable defined in the powershell script

Comment: I fix my issue by upgrading to sharepoint 2019 clean install. no idea what happened to the 2016 install.

Answer (score 2):

Install the security update KB4011244

You can download From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011244/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforsharepointserver2016november14-2017